# cakephp path is pointing to the wrong folder

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a site in cakephp,the issue I am having is the images and css files are pointing to bedutech.com/
while cakephp structure the images are in the `img` folder that is located in : `app/webroot/img`
same goes for the css file so I cant see the site layout properly.
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find out where the bedutech.com is pointing to and whether it's pointing to the server that has your Cakephp site stored. If so, Cakephp has a routing structure so that anything under webroot folder is accessible as a root in URL. This means you can type bedutech.com/img or bedutech.com/css to access webroot/img and webroot/css folders.
If you have trouble finding out whether bedutech.com is actually pointing to your Cakephp server, you can either check DNS records by going to `who.is/bedutech.com` or actually test it  out by typing in the URL in your browser.